# Start workflow when a new item is added to library via email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-activity, incoming-email, email-enabled-library

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have a workflow that is automatically started when something is added to the library. Some things are added to the library via email. I noticed that the things added by email won't have the workflow automatically started. How can i make it so that things added by email ALSO start the workflow? Thanks!

Note: This is a commercial release of SP and the workflow is actually listed as a "SharePoint 2010" workflow.

Edit: I saw [How can I make a workflow automatically start when an email is received?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/how-can-i-make-a-workflow-automatically-start-when-an-email-is-received?rq=1) but will that work for SP 2013? I am not an sys admin so I can't run that command.

Answer (score 1):

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled= $true
$spWebService.Update()
```

Checked on SharePoint 2010 & 2013.

Refer: [SharePoint 2010: Workflows on Incoming Emails in SharePoint Documents Library](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4607.sharepoint-2010-workflows-on-incoming-emails-in-sharepoint-documents-library.aspx)